# "Debug symbol information is required (...)" after injecting modified Spring security expression language implementation

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I have an example class to test `@PreAuthorize` annotations, which looks more or less like this one:

```
class BankService {

    @PreAuthorize("hasCustomRole('ROLE_CUSTOM') or hasRole('ROLE_EXAMPLE')")
    Double getAccountBalance(Integer accountNumber) {
        return 1234;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("#accountNumber > 400")
    int getValue(Integer accountNumber) {
        return 1234;
    }
}
```

You can notice `hasCustomRole(String expression)` in the `@PreAuthorize` annotation, which I'm adding in:

```
public class CustomSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot {

    public CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication auth) {
        super(auth);
    }

    public boolean hasCustomRole(String expression) {
       return /* some magic */;
    }
}
```

Also, I'm extending `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` in the following way:

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

    public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public EvaluationContext createEvaluationContext(Authentication auth, MethodInvocation mi) {
        StandardEvaluationContext ctx = (StandardEvaluationContext) super.createEvaluationContext(auth, mi);
        ctx.setRootObject(new CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(auth));
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

In the end, everything is wrapped in `resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {
  /* ... some stuff ... */

  xmlns security:'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security'

  security.'global-method-security'('pre-post-annotations': 'enabled') {
    security.'expression-handler'(ref: 'expressionHandler')
  }

  expressionHandler(my.package.plugin.security.expression.CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler)
}
```

Now, if I remove the security part from `resources.groovy`, I naturally lose the ability to use the `hasCustomRole()` method, but the following works:

```
assert bankService.getValue(500) == 1234
```

But if I inject my own implementation, the previous statement causes:

```
Access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

After further investigation I found this:

```
prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource Looking for Pre/Post annotations for method 'getValue' on target class 'class my.package.plugin.security.test.BankService'
prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize(value=#accountNumber > 400) found on specific method: public int my.package.plugin.security.test.BankService.getValue(java.lang.Integer)
method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource Adding security method [CacheKey[my.package.plugin.security.test.BankService; public int my.package.plugin.security.test.BankService.getValue(java.lang.Integer)]] with attributes [[authorize: '#accountNumber > 400', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public int my.package.plugin.security.test.BankService.getValue(java.lang.Integer); target is of class [my.package.plugin.security.test.BankService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c590f9ac]; Attributes: [[authorize: '#accountNumber > 400', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken@b35bafc3: Principal: test; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_TELLER
method.MethodSecurityEvaluationContext Unable to resolve method parameter names for method: public final int my.package.plugin.security.test.BankService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c590f9ac.getValue(java.lang.Integer). Debug symbol information is required if you are using parameter names in expressions.
```

The interesting part is `Debug symbol information is required if you are using parameter names in expressions.`, which suggests that classes are compiled without debug information about variable names. But everything works fine if I don't inject my own bean.

What could be the reason for the missing debugging info, and how to fix it?

It's a Grails plugin, developed for Grails 2.0.4, using spring-security-core plugin at version 1.2.7.3, spring-security-acl plugin at version 1.1, and Spring Security 3.0.7.RELEASE.

**EDIT:**

To make the issue more interesting, this is what I discovered later: the "missing" debug information is actually there, if you look into `.class` files with `javap`. So classes are compiled correctly, but Spring complains anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, however, I'm not exactly sure why the exceptions and messages in logs I had been getting were so far from the problem.

I did one mistake assuming that `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` can be used in similar way as in applications built with Grails. And although the documentation doesn't explicitly say that beans configured in `resources.groovy` won't work in this case, it states that `resources.groovy` (among some other files) will be by default excluded from packaging.

It doesn't explain the strange behavior while running tests, but it's not a good place for this kind of configuration.

After moving the Spring Security configuration from `resources.groovy` into the plugin descriptor, in the following way:

```
class MyOwnGrailsPlugin {

  /* ... some stuff ... */

  def doWithSpring = {
    /* ... some spring stuff ... */

    xmlns security:'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security'

    security.'global-method-security'('pre-post-annotations': 'enabled') {
      security.'expression-handler'(ref: 'expressionHandler')
    }

    expressionHandler(my.package.plugin.security.expression.CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler)
  }
}
```

everything works fine and the test passes.